# Regular expression match issue

Tags: regex

I have a simple regular expression: `.}`
and some simple text: `{}}`

Why do I get a single match:

- `{}`

I was expecting to get two:

- `{}`
- `}}`

Please see [here](http://regexr.com/3b67u) for the code snippit.

Comment: Because matches are non-overlapping.

Comment: @Bergi hmm.. I see. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: @smiron I believe look-ahead or look-behind syntax is what you are looking for

Comment: @smiron: Depends on the tool/language you're using that regex in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex matches are non-overlapping. Maybe some like this is closer to what you want:

```
/(?=})}/g
```

I think you actually want look behind not look ahead but this isn't supported on regexr.com because it's not supported in java script

```
/(?<=})}/g
```

Comment: I think you need to add parentheses to enable capturing groups that will return each of the two combinations, i.e. `((?=})})`